# How to implement search in Jetpack Compose - Android

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, android-developer-api

```
var noteListState by remember { mutableStateOf(listOf("Drink water", "Walk")) }
```

This is my list of items. Any leads would be appreciated

Answer (score 6):

**To Get a Main UI with list and searchview**

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContent {
        MainScreen()
    }
}
```

**For Main()**

```
@Composable
fun MainScreen() {
    val textState = remember { mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue("")) }
    Column {
        SearchView(textState)
        ItemList(state = textState)
    }
}
```

**For Serchview and list**

```
@Composable
fun SearchView(state: MutableState<TextFieldValue>) {
    TextField(
        value = state.value,
        onValueChange = { value ->
            state.value = value
        },
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
        textStyle = TextStyle(color = Color.White, fontSize = 18.sp),
        leadingIcon = {
            Icon(
                Icons.Default.Search,
                contentDescription = "",
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(15.dp)
                    .size(24.dp)
            )
        },
        trailingIcon = {
            if (state.value != TextFieldValue("")) {
                IconButton(
                    onClick = {
                        state.value =
                            TextFieldValue("") // Remove text from TextField when you press the 'X' icon
                    }
                ) {
                    Icon(
                        Icons.Default.Close,
                        contentDescription = "",
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .padding(15.dp)
                            .size(24.dp)
                    )
                }
            }
        },
        singleLine = true,
        shape = RectangleShape, // The TextFiled has rounded corners top left and right by default
        colors = TextFieldDefaults.textFieldColors(
            textColor = Color.White,
            cursorColor = Color.White,
            leadingIconColor = Color.White,
            trailingIconColor = Color.White,
            backgroundColor = MaterialTheme.colors.primary,
            focusedIndicatorColor = Color.Transparent,
            unfocusedIndicatorColor = Color.Transparent,
            disabledIndicatorColor = Color.Transparent
        )
    )
}




@Composable
fun ItemList(state: MutableState<TextFieldValue>) {
    val items by remember { mutableStateOf(listOf("Drink water", "Walk")) }

    var filteredItems: List<String>
    LazyColumn(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
        val searchedText = state.value.text
        filteredItems = if (searchedText.isEmpty()) {
            items
        } else {
            val resultList = ArrayList<String>()
            for (item in items) {
                if (item.lowercase(Locale.getDefault())
                        .contains(searchedText.lowercase(Locale.getDefault()))
                ) {
                    resultList.add(item)
                }
            }
            resultList
        }
        items(filteredItems) { filteredItem ->
            ItemListItem(
                ItemText = filteredItem,
                onItemClick = { /*Click event code needs to be implement*/
                }
            )
        }

    }
}



@Composable
fun ItemListItem(ItemText: String, onItemClick: (String) -> Unit) {
    Row(
        modifier = Modifier
            .clickable(onClick = { onItemClick(ItemText) })
            .background(colorResource(id = R.color.purple_700))
            .height(57.dp)
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(PaddingValues(8.dp, 16.dp))
    ) {
        Text(text = ItemText, fontSize = 18.sp, color = Color.White)
    }
}
```

**Update**
SearchView using Material3 (leaving here the imports to avoid conflicts with material 1 or 2):

```
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxWidth
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.padding
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.size
import androidx.compose.material.icons.Icons
import androidx.compose.material.icons.filled.Close
import androidx.compose.material.icons.filled.Search
import androidx.compose.material3.ExperimentalMaterial3Api
import androidx.compose.material3.Icon
import androidx.compose.material3.IconButton
import androidx.compose.material3.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material3.TextField
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.MutableState
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.RectangleShape
import androidx.compose.ui.text.input.TextFieldValue
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp

@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun SearchView(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    state: MutableState<TextFieldValue>
) {
    TextField(
        value = state.value,
        onValueChange = { value ->
            state.value = value
        },
        modifier = modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
        textStyle = MaterialTheme.typography.bodyMedium.copy(color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onPrimary),
        leadingIcon = {
            Icon(
                Icons.Default.Search,
                contentDescription = "",
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(15.dp)
                    .size(24.dp)
            )
        },
        trailingIcon = {
            if (state.value != TextFieldValue("")) {
                IconButton(
                    onClick = {
                        state.value =
                        TextFieldValue("") // Remove text from TextField when you press the 'X' icon
                    }
                ) {
                    Icon(
                        Icons.Default.Close,
                        contentDescription = "",
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .padding(15.dp)
                            .size(24.dp)
                    )
                }
            }
        },
        singleLine = true,
        shape = RectangleShape
    )
}
```

For **material3** you should have previously defined the color scheme.

For More Detailed answer you can refer [this](https://johncodeos.com/how-to-add-search-in-list-with-jetpack-compose/) link

Answer (score 0):

Please explain more, this question is a bit short and unclear.

One way (I think you could do) is just to loop through the list and check if an element (of your list) contains that text.

```kotlin
val filterPattern = text.toString().lowercase(Locale.getDefault()) // text you are looking for
for (item in copyList) { // first make a copy of the list
    if (item.name.lowercase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(filterPattern)) {
        filteredList.add(item) // if the item contains that text add it to the list
    }
}
... // here you then override noteListState
```

After you have made the `filteredList` you can just override the `noteListState`. First, make a copy of that list, Then set it back when you don't want to show the filtered results.

Comment: `Please could you explain more, this question is a bit short and unclear.` usually this means that you should avoid trying to answer, ask for more info with comments before attempting an answer without context, you're just wasting your own time and effort

Comment: yeah, that's a fair comment!

Comment: hi @a_local_nobody , I am new to jetpack. And i could'nt thing of anything else.

Comment: Jetpack compose mainly is a ui-library. However, your question sounds like you're just asking for "how to search for a value in a list", which has nothing to do with Ui. Please clarify your intention.

Answer (score 0):

Not the asked question, but if someone wants to use a search bar in Jetpack Compose, Material 3 has released one and it is in the alpha stage for now:

```
implementation 'androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.2.0-alpha02'
```